# dart, how to find memory leaks?

Tags: memory-leaks, dart, memory-profiling

I am trying to use the Observatory tab in dartium dev tools, to find a memory leak in my framework. I have made a test program [here](http://0xor1.net/purity_memory_profile_test/) which should be viewable in js or dart. My goal is to find out where references are holding on to `Massive` objects, which are just wrappers around a `List<double>` with a million `double`s in it. If I click `New Client` I get a new client view on the right, if I generate a bunch of `Massive` objects and refresh the observatory tools I see that `double` now takes up most of the app memory usage. If I then delete the `Massive` objects and wait 5 seconds for the frameworks remote garbage collection to run, then refresh the observatory tab, the `double`s still occupy the same amount of memory even though they should have been GC'd (I click the GC button on the observatoy tab to, I assume, force the GC to run.) If I keep creating and deleting `Massive` objects in the app eventually the page crashes, typically after around 28 `Massive` objects have been created. My problem is finding out how to use the tools to find out where the `Massive` objects are still having references hold on to them. Is it possible to get find references to objects in the dev tools?

UPDATE:

I have fixed the memory leak in the test app I link too and describe above, therefore following the instructions above will not result in recreating the memory leak.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm currently investigating a memory leak myself. What's missing in the observatory is a way the chain from the root to the leaking object. I'm not sure if there is already an issue open for it, though. Feel free to open a new one.